# Confused behaviour of Pandas indexer .loc

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following DataFrame:

```
df = DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3]})
```

which corresponds to:

```
   A
0  1
1  2
2  3
```

If I replace values of two rows using `.loc` indexer in the following way:

```
data.loc[[1, 0], 'A'] = [101, 100]
```

then I get expected (ordering of the values reflects ordering of the indices):

```
     A
0  101
1    2
2  103
```

However, if I replace values of all rows in the following way:

```
data.loc[[2, 0, 1], 'A'] = [1003, 1001, 1002]
```

then I get unexpected (ordering of the values doesn't reflect ordering of the indices):

```
      A
0  1003
1  1001
2  1002
```

Is it `.loc` feature or a bug? I use Pandas 0.13.0.

Thanks.

Comment: I suppose this *was* a bug, as this works correctly on the development version.

Comment: Yes this works correctly in 0.13.1 so it looks like a bug in 0.13.0

Comment: This was a bug fixed in 0.13.1

Comment: Also, note above that 'data.' should be 'df.', and the "expected" result of your first substitution is NOT expected, your third and first index changed even though you'd supplied second and first [1, 0].